# Migration from 2008r2 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I need to migrate from **SqlServer 2008r2** to **SqlServer 2016**. While migrating will I face any code changes that i have written in **SqlServer 2008** and also Confirm is there any other impacts..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not a question about programming.

Comment: its general question which developer face in her carrier. also its pure technology related question. we need to motivate the person for this type of question. there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @Ajay2707 does sql server 2016 supports encryption like 'SHA1' type of encryption?

Comment: Here is clear indication "Beginning with SQL Server 2016, all algorithms other than SHA2_256, and SHA2_512 are deprecated. "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql

Comment: Can i change my compatibility level to 100 in sql server 2016 and i can write 2008 deprecated features does they support this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016)

Do the search on that page for "discontinued", these features will break your code if you've used them

Answer (score 0):

General rules :- There is no impact comes when you go higher version migration in **SqlServer**.

I give you one by one answer.

> I need to migrate from Sql Server 2008r2 to sql server 2016. While
>   migrating will I face any code changes

No impact comes in code, if everything same you migrate. Only your connection string will change as per new db.

> i have written in sql server 2008 and also Confirm is there any other
>   impacts.. Thanks in advance

I think you telling about Database objects, so my answer is nothing impact. no single change you need.

See other answer : [Impact on application in migrating from sql server 2005 to 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209338/impact-on-application-in-migrating-from-sql-server-2005-to-2008)